# Operational Procedure = liu shui; which characters?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I hear the term "liu shui" often which means something like business procedure, or procedure (a row of actions).

now I am wondering what the correct characters for this (slang?) term may be.

流水 means "flowing water / business turnover." Is it that?

Comment: ```银行帐单流水``` means transactions here.

Answer (score 1):

I just got confirmation from one of my (Chineses) Colleagues that this actually **is** 流水 (flowing water).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the operating model of "流水(式)作業" (flow operation).

a production line (生產缐) or assembly line (流水线) in factory is a typical type of flow operation

A company divided into departments and operating like an assembly line can be called 流水式運作. works flow from one department down to another like water in river

流水作業 and 流水式運作 are common terms for describing a assembly line like operating model

Comment: thanks or those comments. Actually in our compay just 流水 is a pretty well used and apparently cristal clear term for something like procedure in the sense of (pre-defined) sequence of steps